# How to constantly rename a file and move it

Tags: c#, image, directory, move

I am trying to constantly rename and move an image to another folder. This folder is used for database so i am trying to store all the images inside this folder . Thus, i needed to rename each image constantly so they will not overwrite each other. (Some renaming convention : images.jpg, images1.jpg, images2.jpg)

I saw the move method but it doesn't let me constantly change the file name and maybe use a for loop to loop it. However, if i am going to detect if the images already exist and move on to a new name? ( Example : images1.jpg already exist but the program is going to replace it.)

Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var files = new List<string>();

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"Your Location"))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

    if (fileName.StartsWith("Image"))
    {
        files.Add(fileName.Replace("Image",""));
    } 
}

var last = int.Parse(files.OrderByDescending(f => f.ToString()).First()) + 1;
```

To get the next index available, then just move it to where ever you need

Answer (score 1):

I see a few answers here that are re-inventing the wheel.

.net covers this scenario with [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using get random file name

```
string randomFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
//now save the file or whatever you want to do with it.
//you could also remove the trailing charcaters after the .
//and replace them with a meaningful extention. E.g. .jpg
```

Comment: Well the problem is OP's question is kind of off. Anyway, thanks for the info those are some interesting methods! :)

Comment: @TzahMama, I aggree the question is not exactly clear! If they are after a more predictable naming scenario yours may be the better option, though if the number of files in the pertinant directories is large, performance may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming a file and moving it constantly, why not use a GUID which is pretty unique and save that?

`var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());`

Answer (score 0):

while move file from one folder to another. if file exist with name then rename filename and move it ot another folder

```
 DirectoryInfo orginalLocation = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\a");
        DirectoryInfo DestinationLocation = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\b");
        List<string> fileNameInDestinationLocation = DestinationLocation.GetFiles("*.*").Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s.FullName)).ToList<string>();
        FileInfo[] orginalLocationFiles = orginalLocation.GetFiles("*.*");

        orginalLocationFiles.ToList<FileInfo>().ForEach(s => {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(s.FullName);
            while (fileNameInDestinationLocation.Contains(fileName))
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                fileName = r.Next(100, 1000000).ToString() + fileName;
            }

            s.MoveTo(@"C:\b\" + fileName);
        });
```